# Using boolean subqueries in SELECT

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT A.ID AS Asta
    ,B.GPS.Lat AS Lng
    ,B.GPS.Long AS Lat
    ,B.Tipo AS Tipo
    ,B.Via AS Via
    ,A.Stato AS Stato
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM SIBA_Vendite
        WHERE Lotto = B.Lotto
            AND Data > GETDATE()
        ) AS Attiva
    ,(
        SELECT TOP (1) Esito
        FROM SIBA_Vendite
        WHERE Lotto = B.Lotto
        ORDER BY Data
        ) = (
        SELECT ID
        FROM SIBA_Esiti
        WHERE NAME = 'DESERTA'
        ) AS Deserta
FROM SIBA_Beni B
INNER JOIN SIBA_Aste A ON B.Asta = A.ID
```

is returning

```
Messaggio 102, livello 15, stato 1, riga 1
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Messaggio 156, livello 15, stato 1, riga 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

The wrong piece is the = between two subqueries. I'm trying to get a boolean result of the = as "Deserta" field

Comment: You need a `CASE` expression

Comment: There's no boolean [data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187752.aspx) in SQL Server - as such, you can't create an expression that produces one as a result.

Comment: Generally speaking, the query design is very bad. If tables are long (with 100,000+ rows) it will be very slow and heavy. And can be redesigned to work much faster without such subselects.

Comment: Well, technically there is [a Boolean data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx), but it can't be used for columns, variables, or in result sets.  Boolean is what Comparison and Logical operators use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server doesn't have a boolean datatype, so you have no choice but to use a `case` or an `iif` expression to handle this case.
e.g.

```
Deserta =case when (SELECT TOP (1) Esito
        FROM SIBA_Vendite
        WHERE Lotto = B.Lotto
        ORDER BY Data) = (
        SELECT ID
        FROM SIBA_Esiti
        WHERE NAME = 'DESERTA'
        ) then 1 else 0 end
```